# Using Google analytics need to papulate a report how many user comes to our site through fecebook ads

Tags: google-analytics, tags, seo, tracking, facebook-ads-api

We are using Word Press Multiple sites network for our organization: www.exaple.com/[multiple-subsites-here]

like www.example.com/subsite1/, www.example.com/subsite2/, www.example.com/subsite3/ etc
Also we have a sub domain like: survey.example.com where we have a survey web form.

Now we are trying to track number of users who could reach on each sub-sites using facebook to survey site and then subsite.

Some more Details:

Users comes to survey.example.com through facebook ads and after completing survey we are forwarding user to one of our sub site based on survey answer. So user flow is like:

User A: ads.facebook.com->webform.example.com->www.example.com/subsite1/

User B: ads.facebook.com->webform.example.com->www.example.com/subsite2/

User C: ads.facebook.com->webform.example.com->www.example.com/subsite6/

User D: ads.facebook.com->webform.example.com->www.example.com/subsite1/

So for all sub-sites we have created Google analytics views in a single account Like:

Webform view for:webform.example.com

Sub-site1 view for:www.example.com/subsite1/

Sub site2 view for:www.example.com/subsite2/ etc.

On “Webform” View:
We are able to calculate the user who comes from facebook Ads using Google analytic Gols through referrers etc.

On “subsite1” view:
We are able to calculate how many user comes from survey web forms to sub-site using Google analytic Gols through referrers etc.

The Issue is:

We need to calculate the user who comes from facebook to survey site and then reached to each sub-site.Any Idea how it could be achieve?

Umair

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics usage and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it is something about programing too, we need to create cookies and other stuff i think.